# Can ENOENT mean too many files on partition?

Tags: c++

When calling access(2) and getting an errno == ENOENT the man page says:

```
   ENOENT A directory component in pathname would have been accessible but
          does not exist or was a dangling symbolic link.
```

However, in my case I was trying to create a file in /tmp/ and the directory component was accessible and exists.  Could it be that ENOENT is also given when the file system has too many files in a directory?  In my case, /tmp/ had grown to an enormous number of small temporary files.  Can I eventually reach a limit and get this ENOENT?  If so, how can I programmatically differentiate this case?

-- More stripped down code added and more explaination --

Looking closer, it appears that the file exists on disk, although if that is case, why would mkstemp() give me a collision?  I doubt I could I have exhausted the XXXXXX space, 36^6 = 2.1 billion!

```
char *fileName = new char[256];

strncpy(fileName, "/tmp/somePathXXXXXX", 255);

int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(fileName);

if (fileDescriptor == -1) {
  struct stat statusFileInfo;
  int result = stat(fileName, &statusFileInfo);

  if (result == 0) {
    mode_t mode = statusFileInfo.st_mode;

    if (S_ISREG(mode)) {
      // Check permission.
      int result = access(fileName, W_OK);

      if (result) {
        // Code landed here with errno == ENOENT.
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note my application's code has worked fine for thousands of invocations, then I saw this one failure.  The code above is a simplified synthesis down to the key ingredients of the failure condition.

Comment: `access` is prone to race conditions. If your goal is to create a unique temp file, you should be attempting to create the file with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` and reacting to failures when the file exists. That, or use a libc function which generates temp files instead of trying to do it yourself.

Comment: @asveikau I've added code showing that I am using mkstemp() to generate the temporary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main meaning of ENOENT is 'no such file or directory'.  It means that the name you tried to `access()` was not there.

If you were trying to create the file, then maybe, perhaps, you would get ENOENT when there are 'too many files in a directory', but you'd be more likely to get some other error, I think - perhaps ENOSPC (no space left on the device) if there was a problem with your inode table overflowing.

---

The code that appeared since I wrote the first part of the answer needs correcting.

```
char *fileName = "/tmp/somePathXXXXXX";
int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(fileName);
```

You are lucky - or maybe unlucky - that this did not cause a segmentation fault.  That is categorically not the correct way to call [`mkstemp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) or any of the related functions.  You must pass a modifiable string, and that is a string constant, and hence not modifiable.  It might well be stored in read-only memory.  It seems that you got away with it - but on the second invocation, you are passing a string that does not have 6 X's in it (because `mkstemp()` wrote over the X's the first time).  So, it is no wonder that the file already exists.

If you're going to play like that, you must use something equivalent to:

```
const char refFileName[] = "/tmp/somePathXXXXXX";
char fileName[32];
strcpy(fileName, refFileName);
int fd = mkstemp(fileName);
```

Now the `mkstemp()` function has modifiable text to work with.

Comment: Sorry my simplification introduced the memory error.  In my actual code the memory is allocated for the filename on the heap.  Will update question above.

Comment: @WilliamKF your test for successful return from mkstemp() is still wrong

Comment: @MK: WilliamKF is looking at the failure return, not the successful return.  He's trying to work out what went wrong when `mkstemp()` failed.

Comment: oh, you are right.  But the buffer will still contain XXXXX so not much sense in the test.

Comment: @MK: the standard is silent on whether the argument will be unmodified on failure.  I also note the WilliamKF does not look at the errno set by `mkstemp()`, which is odd.  It would be sensible to diagnose the issues by printing the file name before and after, too.  I tried a test program.  It generated 10,000 files safely in the current directory; it then failed to create one in a non-existent sub-directory.  I generated the error:  "`Failed: ./x/x-OhWrPQ (2: No such file or directory)`".  This shows that on Linux, the template was modified by `mkstemp()` even when the function failed. YMMV.